# Codeigniter select relation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have three database tables: data1, data2, data3 for example. 
Data1 is a parts table, data2 is a product table and data3 is a relationship table.

The users can select multiple parts from data1 to create product combinations in data2. The combinations are stores in data3.

data3 has these columns:

- id
- relid
- reltype
- partid

For explanation: When I select a product with id 6, I have to select every item with relid 6 and show all parts from data1 (column partid).

I have written a little bit of code but I'm stuck:

MODEL:

```
 public function example()
{
    $this->db->select('relid');
    $this->db->from('data3');
    $sub_query = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('data2');
    $this->db->where("id IN ($sub_query)" AND ("reltype=1") );
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

Can anybody help me out with checking the model and with the right controller code?

**EDIT**

I get a error when i try the suggestion:

```
$this->db->select('*')
->from('data3')
->join('data1', 'data3.partid = data1.id', 'left')
->where('data3.relid', 6)
->get()->result_array();
```

Message: Call to a member function result() on null

Code in controller:

```
$data['parts'] = $this->example_model->example();
```

Code in view:

```
<?php foreach($parts->result() as $part) { ?>
<div class="parts">
<?php echo $part->id; ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: 1 database 3 tables, right? Or is it 3 databases 1 table in each?

Comment: Yes, 1 database and 3 tables

Comment: so user have store and store have products or user have products and products have stores ?

Comment: Can you provide your tables definition?

Comment: What I understood is you have three tables *Parts(data1)*,*Products(data2)*,*Relationship(data3)* .

If you select `data3.relid = 6`, You need all the *data1.id* related to that relid should be displayed. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's right Avinash. 

It's a project management system where the user can make product combinations. User add a product on data2 and select the related parts from data 1. In addition, it can be divided into categories (reltype). 

When the user opens a product in data2 it must show the related parts from data1. In different tabs.

Sorry for my bad English :) I hope it is clearer now

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be possible with a simple left join query, give this a try.

```
$this->db->select('*')
        ->from('data3')
        ->join('data1', 'data3.partid = data1.id', 'left')
        ->where('data3.relid', 6)
        ->get()->result_array();
```